# How to identify the same image in a faster way

Tags: ruby, image, hash, md5, digest

I have a lot pictures some of are totally identical except the file name, currently I group them by calculating each pic's MD5, but it looks very slow to hash each of them. Is there any alternative way to make it faster? Will it help if I resize the image before hash?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]". We'd like to know what effort you've put into your question to solve it. Where did you search? Why didn't those results help? Did you write code? If not, why? If you did, why didn't you show it to us? Asking for advice is OK, but you need to ask on SO as a final resort after doing your research and right now we see no evidence of that research. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421 Also, how rigorous do you need your test to be? To the eye a picture can be identical to another, but the MD5 will differ because the bytes are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group files by `[filesize, partial hashcode]`, "partial hashcode" being a hash for (say) some block of `[N, filesize].min` bytes in the file (e.g., at the beginning or end of the file). Naturally, the choice of `N` affects the probability of two different files being grouped together, but that might be acceptable if the probability and/or cost of creating an erroneous grouping are sufficiently small.

Comment: Lazy-evaluating all of this would make for a pretty slick comparison operation. A wrapper class with a custom comparator, for example. `a.size == b.size && a.head_hash == b.head_hash && a.full_hash == b.full_hash` could do it.

Comment: Outstanding answer!  Compared to the cost of a full MD5 hash or the (egads!) image resizing, this would perform soundly for any size image, or even for virtually any content type.

Comment: Cary, thank you again to answer my question! Do a less complicated hash is also what I was thinking about, but I have no idea of how to pick the right N to balance the trade off of the accuracy.

Comment: I'm guessing that a hashcode of the first 4K bytes combined with the last 4K bytes would work fine. It doesn't have to be MD5. Find a source of a large number of image files (from Google, perhaps) and test.

Answer (score 0):

MD5 the pic's with multiple processes if you're using CRuby, or multiple thread if you're using Rubinius or JRuby

### Multiprocess

```
workers = 4  # >= number of CPU cores

file_groups = Dir['/path/to/pic/folder/*'].each_with_index.group_by{|filename, i| i % workers}.values

file_groups.each do |group|
  fork do
    group.each do |filename, _|
      # MD5 the file
    end
  end
end

Process.waitall
```

## Multithread

```
workers = 4  # >= number of CPU cores

file_groups = Dir['/path/to/pic/folder/*'].each_with_index.group_by{|filename, i| i % workers}.values

threads = file_groups.map do |group|
  Thread.new do
    group.each do |filename, _|
      # MD5 the file
    end
  end
end

threads.each(&:join)
```

Comment: "CRuby" isn't a thing (are you thinking of CPython?). The Ruby runtime implemented in C is called MRI (Matz's Ruby Interpreter).

Comment: Better than grouping is using [Queue](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Queue.html) to delegate across threads.